# Lightning component docs are not avialbe

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, error

Why every lightning document that I'm trying to open give me the next error :

[image]

Example Urls:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:card

Actually all the next prefix:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library

I tried different Browsers... same for all of them - But it working partially in my mobile chrome somehow..

My Chrome error (On Windows) :

[image]

Comment: That's weird. Did you try to delete your browser cache?

Comment: Have you tried in incognito mode?

Comment: Hi, Both  - clearing the browser cache and from incognito mode give the same error

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why this happens on Chorme\ Explorer - But on Firefox it's working fine.

Because this is an uncomfortable solution I will not post this as an answer.

Hoping for someone who can share his knowledge about this - for entering to docs with the same browser I'm working on...

- Not working :

  1.Clear the browser cache

  2.Incognito mode